# Server 2016, Using Different Bootfiles to Deploy Company Specific Images

Tags: windows, dhcp, pxe-boot, wds

I have a switch with 3 VLANs. I have a WDS server (with DHCP and DNS) with 3 virtual NICs, each NIC is tied to one of those VLANs. Each VLAN corresponds to a company that we work with. I have 3 scopes setup, so that a computer plugged into a port corresponding with VLAN 1 gets an IP from the range designated to company 1. I am trying to set up my scopes so that, when pxe booted, these computers receive a company specific image.

I know that I can set option 67 to point to a specific bootfile, but am unclear on if I am able to have distinct bootfiles, each pointing to a specific image. Ideally I would have:

- Port 1 (VLAN 1) -> Scope 1 -> Bootfile 1 -> Company A Image
- Port 2 (VLAN 2) -> Scope 2 -> Bootfile 2 -> Company B Image
- Port 3 (VLAN 3) -> Scope 3 -> Bootfile 3 -> Company C Image

Is this possible? Is there another way I can accomplish this?

Thanks for guidance, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do this.

But the way I would do it is to use MDT (Microsoft Deployment Toolkit) along with WDS. It’s a far more powerful and flexible deployment system designed for supporting multiple different deployment scenarios.

With MDT you could setup a single automated task sequence and choose your “apply image task” based on a WMI filter for IP address or default gateway of the client system.

Set the new task sequence as the default and tweak other options in customsettings.ini and you’ll have a fully automated deployment with images based on subnet.

Add to that the flexibility of customizing drivers and deploying applications based on machine type and location and it seems like the way to go. If you’re deploying a lot of systems it’s the only way to go in my opinion.